# Counting times values occured in Array

Tags: c#, arrays, count

I am having a hard time with a program I need to write. The requirements are that the user enters in the size of the Array. Then they enter the elements of the array after this the program needs to display the values entered then how many times each value occurs. While everything seems to work except its not display the "occurs" part properly. Lets say "1 1 2 3 4" is entered (Array size being 5) It prints

```
1 occurs 1 time. 
1 occurs 1 time. 
2 occurs 1 time. 
3 occurs 1 time. 
4 occurs 2 times.
```

this isn't right because 1 occured 2 times and 4 is only 1 time. Please Help...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[30];
        int size,
            count=0,
            count1=0,
            count2=0;

        Console.Write("Enter Size of the Array: ");
        size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter the elements of an Array: ");
        for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       }

        Console.Write("Values Entered: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            if (arr[i] <= 10)
                count++;
            else
                count1++;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                    count2++;
                else
                    count2 = 1;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + " Occurs " + count2 + " Times.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The number of valid entries are: " + count + "\nThe number of invalid entries are: " + count1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use Linq?

Comment: Just a thought, but wouldn't it be better to initialize the array when told the size? `int[] arr = new arr[size]`

Comment: If you aren't allowed to use Linq, what other (arbitrary) constraints are there to what you can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can use Linq, this is easy job:

After

```
Console.Write("Values Entered: \n");
```

add

```
var grouped = arr.GroupBy(x => x);
foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("number {0} occurs {1} times", group.Key, group.Count());
}
```

**EDIT**

Since OP isn't allowed to use Linq, here's *array-only* solution. Much more code than that dictionary approach, but with arrays only.

```
Console.Write("Values Entered: \n");
//an array to hold numbers that are already processed/counted. Inital length is as same as original array's
int[] doneNumbers = new int[arr.Length];
//counter for processed numbers
int doneCount = 0;
//first loop
foreach (var element in arr)
{
    //flag to skip already processed number 
    bool skip = false;
    //check if current number is already in "done" array
    foreach (int i in doneNumbers)
    {
        //it is!
        if (i == element)
        {
            //set skip flag
            skip = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    //this number is already processed, exit loop to go to next one
    if (skip)
        continue;

    //it hasn't been processed yes, so go through another loop to count occurrences
    int occursCounter = 0;
    foreach (var element2 in arr)
    {
        if (element2 == element)
            occursCounter++;
    }

    //number is processed, add it to "done" list and increase "done" counter
    doneNumbers[doneCount] = element;
    doneCount++;

    Console.WriteLine("number {0} occurs {1} times", element, occursCounter);
}
```

Comment: I seen some stuff with a google search on this. So I checked and I can't use Linq. This is getting very frustrating to say the least haha

Comment: Why the downvotes? At the time OP asked for a solution, I provided working one (Linq was "allowed").... so I'm not sure I understand why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: @Ken, I'm not accusing you nor anyone...It doesn't matter who did it, I wanted to know what is wrong with answer... to delete it or improve.

Comment: Thanks for the code you provided. I can certainly see how this is more code than your first answer using linq. I am actually unaware of what Linq is but looking at my book we learn that in about 400 pages... ha ha.. My last two lines of code show what valid entries were put in and what was invalid. So it looks like I just need to update that section. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use dictionary:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        Console.Write("Enter Size of the Array: ");
        int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter the elements of an Array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            int val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int current;
            if (dic.TryGetValue(i, out current))
            {
                dic[val] = current + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                dic.Add(val, 1);
            }
        }

        foreach (int key in dic.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(key + " Occurs " + dic[key] + " Times.");
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're resetting `count2` to `1` any time you find a mismatch.

What you should do instead is set `count2` to `0` in the outer loop (so it basically resets once for each item), and then let the inner loop count all the instances of that number:

```
// For each item 'i' in the array, count how many other items 'j' are the same
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    count2 = 0; // processing a new item, so reset count2 to 0

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]) count2++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + " occurs " + count2 + " times.");
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: The only thing to figure out now is lets say I have an Array size of 4 then enter "4" in 4 times. How to get it not to print 4 occurred 4 times ..... 4 times in a row.

Comment: It doesn't actually say it can't be displayed over and over so I am rolling with what I have.

Comment: @KenYoung I have edited my answer and provided solution without duplicated lines, and with arrays only... check it out.